# "Popular tag sets" in Stack Exchange stats not sorted correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, statistics

I am looking at https://stackexchange.com/tagsets right now. This is what I see:

[image]

It appears that the list is not reordered every time a number changes. I understand that it might be very much intentional, in order to improve performance, but it is rather confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort order is correct.  We don't actually sort by total # of views, we sort by a hotness score based on recent views.  I agree that it's confusing, though, to show the views when we *almost* sort by them, so now we'll show the recent views instead of total views.

It still says "views" instead of "recent views" because "recent views" was too long and the distinction seems insignificant.